# Python ConfigParser - raise KeyError (key)

Tags: python, configparser

config.ini

```
[datasource]
host = localhost
```

config.py

```
import configparser
import os

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'config.ini'))
host = config['datasource']['host']
```

Test.py

```
import config
print(config.host)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "Test\test.py", line 6, in
>
> import config
>
> File "C:\Users\jack\PycharmProjects\Test\config.py", line 6, in
>
> host = config['datasource']['host']
>
> File "C:\Users\jack\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\configparser.py", line 958, in **getitem**
>
> raise KeyError(key)
>
> KeyError: 'datasource'

All the files are put in the same folder.

When I run Test.py script from the pycharm it does not have problem.

But when I calling from terminal the error come.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Presumably because the working directory is different, so `os.getcwd()` gives a different location. You almost certainly don't want to do that anyway.

Comment: Print out `os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'config.ini')` to see where Python is looking for your file there.

Comment: `config.read(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'config.ini'))` won't raise any `OSError` even if the path is not exist. Instead it return [empty list](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/configparser.py#L693).

Comment: @DanielRoseman okay. The `os.getcwd()` point to the "C:\Users\jack\PycharmProjects\" and I change the path without using `os.getcwd()` and it works in terminal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the config file is placed in the same directory

Just get the config.py file location, remove config.py file name and join with the config.ini file

```
path = '/'.join((os.path.abspath(__file__).replace('\\', '/')).split('/')[:-1])
config.read(os.path.join(path, 'config.ini'))
```

By this you not need keep changing the file path even you move the whole directory

Comment: If `config.py` and `config.ini` are in the same directory, why you don't use `config.read('config.ini')`?

Comment: I try this before but it keep raise me the error so I leave my solution. If there is another best way to solve this then just go ahead with that

Comment: ok, I have another suggestion for getting path above: `os.path.split(path_to_file)[0].replace('\\','/')`. This `os.path.split()` will split file path in to folder path and file name.